# What is the best algorithm for computing rectilinear minimum Steiner tree?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, approximation

There are many algorithms that find approximations of rectilinear Steiner minimum trees (RSMT). Among them are:

- a suite of algorithms that find minimum spanning trees
- RST-T (rectilinear single trunk Steiner tree)
- BGA (batcheed greedy algorithm)
- BI1S (Batched Iterated 1-Steiner tree)
- FLUTE (Fast Lookup Table Based Technique for RSMT Construction and Wirelength Estimation)

It was showed that length of RSMT can be as much as 3/2 times that of rectlinear spanning minimum tree. I didn't find in literature bounds for other algorithms. Do they exist?

FLUTE seems to be the most efficient algorithm from all but I don't know it's worst case and upper bound. Was it found?

Does any algorithm have bound less than 3/2?

Answer (score 2):

[Arora](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/tsp.ps) and [Mitchell](ftp://ftp.ams.sunysb.edu/pub/geometry/tsp-final.ps.gz) gave polynomial-time approximation schemes (= for all epsilon > 0, a (1 + epsilon)-approximation) for Euclidean Steiner tree. I believe the ideas can be adapted straightforwardly to the rectilinear variant.

Comment: Algorithm seems to have very high computational complexity - O(n^O(m))

Comment: What's m? Arora got the running time down to O(f(epsilon) n polylog(n)).